# Wordpress list_pages setting the li attribute and a drop down menu

Tags: wordpress

I am writing a website based off of wordpress and am having some difficulties.  I know I can use 
`<?php wp_list_pages('title_li=&depth=1'); ?>`

However, how can I assign a mouseover attribute to the `<li>` that is created?  Also, if there are children pages, they need to be in a nested `<ul>` and show as a dropdown when the parent is hovered on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Review the "Markup and Styling" Section of the [Codex page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pages) for `wp_list_pages`.  It describes how a `page_item` class is applied to each `<li>`.  Use that class to assign your mouseover attribute on the client side.  If you are not using jQuery, I recommend it.

You can use `get_pages()` to create your child page dropdown menu's.  The same Codex page I linked to above describes using this function to get all your page_id's.  You can then iterate over them and use `get_pages()` again specifying that you want to retrieve only child pages of the given page id.  Using css to hide the child page dropdown lists, you can use javascript again to show the dropdowns when the pages are moused-over in the parent page menu.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function get_pages() instead, that will give you an array of the pages, and not printing the html, so you can build it by yourself, having the flexibility to pick the attributes of

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_pages